# What is wrong with my code to run HTML within PHP?

Tags: php, html, xampp

I have been trying to learn PHP using a book (PHP for Absolute Beginners).
I have entered the code exactly as shown in the book but it doesn't work. I am running it through XAMPP and my code up until now has been working.
I was wondering if anyone can tell me what is wrong with the code below?

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );
$title="Test title";
$content="<h1>Hello World</h1>";
$page="
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>$title</title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type'content='text/html;charset=utf-8/>
</head>
<body>
$content
</body>
</html>";
echo $page;
```

Thanks very much

Dave

Comment: What is the error? What are you getting? What are the output?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: is your file a .html or .php ?

Answer (score 2):

Fix the line    :

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type'content='text/html;charset=utf-8/>
```

to

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
```

or, better yet, to:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

since you're making HTML5 code.

Comment: Hard to tell what OP's issue is, but this typo certainly can't be helping, with the missing `'` at the end.

Comment: Might be because you said "remove" instead of "fix", but you don't deserve the downvotes you're getting here. Weird. I've tweaked your answer.

Comment: OP is missing a lot of information, but that single quote is causing the HTML to break... so adding the single quote will fix the output..

Comment: @ceejayoz That, plus the fact that it randomly says to remove a line without explaining why/what is wrong with it. I did not spot the missing quote at first sight and that line might be there for a good reason.  And also this is just a guess to an unclear question that might have a complete different cause.